# How to get DataTables Ajax parameters

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables with server-side processing.

I want to create a button. When that button is clicked, it should send current DataTable parameters (search, sort, etc) to the server-side script to generate MS Excel file using PHPExcel.

Comment: What have you tried to accomplish that? It's important to know [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve the chances of getting a good answer. Please, edit your question to include that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ajax.params()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.params%28%29) to get the data submitted by DataTables to the server in the last Ajax request.

Then you can redirect to script that generates Excel file with these parameters using jQuery helper function [`$.param`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) that converts array into query string.

For example:

```
window.location = '/getFile.php?' + $.param($('#example').DataTable().ajax.params());
```

where `example` is table ID.